# Pre-load specific entities (tables) in l2 cache with JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am wondering whether it is possible to pre-load specific sets of entities (i.e. static lookup tables) into the L2 cache using generic JPA settings. Is this possible or is it JPA vendor (Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc...) dependant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there's a setting for such a task.
However, what seemed to work when I tried exactly that, is a simple JPQL query, which should fetch the objects into the second level cache (at least Hibernate did that):

```
entityManager.createQuery("select x from Entity x").getResultList();
```

This is plain JPA and therefore not vendor dependent and could be executed in a constructor of a corresponding DAO (`@Repository` or `@Service` in Spring) or in a prefetch thread.

Comment: Although this would pre populate the L2 cache, I read that when the cache's object limit is reached, objects are discarded at random (at least this was the behaviour for IBM websphere). I would hope for a way to specify that the entity remain in the cache for the duration of the application.

Comment: I don't know of a way to pin cache entries via Hibernate. However, EHCache would allow that: http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/data-life. You'd need to investigate, what that websphere cache has to offer (I don't know that thing). When I think about it, a halfway smart cache implementation should cling to those hot sections anyway, if you use them frequently. Nowadays, caches have more than one eviction strategy. See LFU: http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-eviction-algorithms .However, Pinning works against a cache. One may just detach the objects into an own map.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know of any such JPA feature. I'd simply trigger the respective calls (services, repositories, DAOs or whatever they are) during startup of your application.

Given the 2nd-level cache is properly setup and configured the entities representing your static lookup tables will remain in the cache until...well, that depends of course on your caching settings.